# Disabling price cache in UberCart?

Tags: drupal, caching, ubercart

How do you disable the caching of selling price in UberCart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to:

Store Administration > Configuration > Price handler settings

and then disable 'Cache generated price values until the next cron run'